# Make a Non-Gradle IntelliJ idea Project into a Project using Gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on an Android Project in IntelliJ Idea, which doesn't use gradle, but now I want to include Gradle in there. I know this is possible, because the option once appeared to me, but I don't know where it was. (If you're wondering, because my project doesn't use gradle, my gradle window is disabled as well)

How can I switch to gradle?

Comment: If there is not an option like import project without gradle you need to do it manually, importing the classes and switch everything you can to gradle

Comment: Alright, seems like that was the only option, thank you